# Trouble accessing the first column of a dataset in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I work in RStudio

After importing my dataset with the function:

```
mydata <- read.table("dataset.txt",sep="\t",dec=",", h=T, row.names=1)
```

the file is imported and I can see it in RStudio. Then, I would like to look at my data:

```
table (column2, column3)   # it does work and give me the table
```

everything looks OK. However, if I ask for the First column

```
table (column1, column2)    # it doesn't work!
```

I received the error message:

```
"Error in table(column1) : object 'ID_site' not found"
```

It seems the first column is not part of my dataset...

Do you know Why? Is there an option to choose before data importation?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `row.names=1` part from your `read.table` call. When you do that, R takes the first column of your dataset and uses it as the rownames of your data frame. That, in turn removes the ID of the column, which is why R says your "ID_site" column can't be found.